# Is it possible for local maximum value to be smaller than local minimum? I got such a solution.

Tags: calculus, functions

In the following function:
$f(x) = (x^2-x+1)/(1-x)$

I got that minimum $f(0) = 1$
and maximum $f(2) = -3$

Wolfram also says so... but why is it?

Comment: This is surely possible, and it is precisely because it is just a local maximum and minimum, which means it is just the highest / lowest value in a neighbourhood of that point, not for the function as a whole

Comment: You'd be surprised if that happened when the domain of your function was an interval; but here the domain is not an interval, and all bets are off.

Comment: In $x+\frac{1}{x}$, the minima (2) > maxima (-2).

Answer (score 4):

I like to look at your equation as two parts, since there is an asymptope at $x=1$ . Look at the following graph

[image]

You can see that the part on the left has no local max, but has a local min, while the part on the right has a local max, but no local min

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for instance the secant function $x\mapsto\frac1{\cos x}$ has local minima of value $1$ at even multiples of$~\pi$, and local maxima of value $-1$ at odd multiples of$~\pi$. The function being continuous where it is defined, it is essential that it is undefined at least once between such a local minimum and local maximum, so that the function value can jump from very large (tending to $+\infty$) to very small (tending to $-\infty$) or back; the secant function does this at odd multiples of $\frac\pi2$.

Your function does something similar, but just once.